# Weird symbols in IPython Notebook

Tags: azure, encoding, jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service

I use cyrillic symbols in my IPython notebooks. It works fine when I work in ML studio.

But when I download notebooks and open them (for example on http://try.jupyter.org ), I see strange characters.

Bad notebook (created on Azure ML Studio):

```
{"nbformat_minor": 0, "cells": [{"source": "\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u0082", "cell_type": "markdown", "metadata": {"collapsed": true}}], "nbformat": 4, "metadata": {"kernelspec": {"display_name": "Python 2", "name": "python2", "language": "python"}, "language_info": {"mimetype": "text/x-python", "nbconvert_exporter": "python", "version": "2.7.11", "name": "python", "file_extension": ".py", "pygments_lexer": "ipython2", "codemirror_mode": {"version": 2, "name": "ipython"}}}}

$ file bad.ipynb 
bad.ipynb: ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
```

"Good" version, created on http://try.jupyter.org:

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "тест"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 2",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python2"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 2
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython2",
   "version": "2.7.10"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 0
}

$ file good.ipynb 
good.ipynb: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Comment: The problem is the encoding. You see the "тест" is not ascii. Hence, the Json parser convert them into Unicode. You need to know the encoding in order to get the real content.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the reason, why this happens, but I can't understand how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some lab, and found out that your json is encoded into utf-8. For your case, it's simple to get the real content back. See the code below:

Python 3.x

```
a = '{"nbformat_minor": 0, "cells": [{"source": "\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u0082", "cell_type": "markdown", "metadata": {"collapsed": true}}], "nbformat": 4, "metadata": {"kernelspec": {"display_name": "Python 2", "name": "python2", "language": "python"}, "language_info": {"mimetype": "text/x-python", "nbconvert_exporter": "python", "version": "2.7.11", "name": "python", "file_extension": ".py", "pygments_lexer": "ipython2", "codemirror_mode": {"version": 2, "name": "ipython"}}}}'

result = a.encode('latin-1').decode("utf-8")
```

Python 2.x

```
a = '{"nbformat_minor": 0, "cells": [{"source": "\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u0082", "cell_type": "markdown", "metadata": {"collapsed": true}}], "nbformat": 4, "metadata": {"kernelspec": {"display_name": "Python 2", "name": "python2", "language": "python"}, "language_info": {"mimetype": "text/x-python", "nbconvert_exporter": "python", "version": "2.7.11", "name": "python", "file_extension": ".py", "pygments_lexer": "ipython2", "codemirror_mode": {"version": 2, "name": "ipython"}}}}'

result = a.decode('unicode-escape').encode("latin-1")
```

This piece of code may not work for some other cases, because 'latin-1' does not cover all 0-255 characters. Hence, I am still looking for a better encoding for this kind of things.

Comment: Thanks, looks like this code works only with Python 3 kernel. But at least I can restore my notebooks now.

Comment: When involving encodings, weird things happen. I have no idea why the python 2.x code would look like that. I just tried it out.